# Position absolute and transition with chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

it seems that Chrome and transition have got a problem with position absolute. I'm testing with Chrome 36.0. It works fine with the latest Firefox and the latest IE.
The problem is that I can't view the submenu when I pass the mouse pointer over Categorias item menu.
The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang='es'>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <title>Menú Desplegable</title>

    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/styles.css' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/fonts.css' />
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href='#'><span class='primero'><i class='icon icon-house'></i></span>Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'><span class='segundo'><i class='icon icon-tag'></i></span>Categorías</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href='#'>Item#1</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#'>Item#2</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#'>Item#3</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#'>Item#4</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#'>Item#5</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href='#'><span class='tercero'><i class='icon icon-suitcase'></i></span>Servicios</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'><span class='cuarto'><i class='icon icon-newspaper'></i></span>Acerca De</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'><span class='quinto'><i class='icon icon-mail'></i></span>Contacto</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS code:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
header {
    width: 100%;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav {
    margin: 20px auto;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1000px;
}
nav ul {
    list-style: none;
}
nav > ul {
    display: table;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
    position: relative;
}
nav > ul li {
    display: table-cell;
}
/*Sub-menu*/
nav > ul > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
}
nav > ul > li > ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: black;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease;
    transition: all .3s ease;
}
nav > ul li a {
    color: white;
    display: block;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease;
    transition: all .3s ease;
}
nav > ul > li > ul > li a:hover {
    background: #5da5a2;
}

nav > ul > li > a span {
    background: #174459;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -55px;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease;
    transition: all .3s ease;
}
nav > ul > li > a span .icon {
    display: block;
    line-height: 60px;
}

nav > ul > li > a:hover > span {
    top: 0;
}

/*Colores*/
nav ul li a .primero {
    background: #0e5061;
}

nav ul li a .segundo {
    background: #5da5a2;
}

nav ul li a .tercero {
    background: #f25724;
}
nav ul li a .cuarto {
    background: #174459;
}

nav ul li a .quinto {
    background: #37a4d9;
}
```

It seems the problem is in this section:

```
nav > ul > li > ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
```

If I change position to relative, then it appears the submenu when I pass the mouse pointer.
I've been reading about that around internet and it seems a bug solved since 16 or 18 Chrome version, but it doesn't seem at all for this code.

Thanks

Comment: You want just to show menu on hover as display block?

Comment: Well, I want to know but this code works fine with firefox and not in Chrome, and a solution

Comment: if i see good, its problem because u have nav>ul overflow: hidden, than when u hover ul>ul cant be visible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fix for your css of menu, so now gonna work:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
header {
    margin-top:10px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav {
    top:-20px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
nav ul {
    list-style: none;
}
nav > ul {
    display: table;

    width: 100%;
    background: black;
    position: relative;
}
nav > ul li {
    display: table-cell;
}
/*Sub-menu*/
nav > ul > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
}
nav > ul > li > ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: black;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease;
    transition: all .3s ease;
}
nav > ul li a {
    color: white;
    display: block;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease;
    transition: all .3s ease;
}
nav > ul > li > ul > li a:hover {
    background: #5da5a2;
}

nav > ul > li > a span {
    background: #174459;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -55px;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease;
    transition: all .3s ease;
}
nav > ul > li > a span .icon {
    display: block;
    line-height: 60px;
}

nav > ul > li > a:hover > span {
    top: 0;
}

/*Colores*/
nav ul li a .primero {
    background: #0e5061;
}

nav ul li a .segundo {
    background: #5da5a2;
}

nav ul li a .tercero {
    background: #f25724;
}
nav ul li a .cuarto {
    background: #174459;
}

nav ul li a .quinto {
    background: #37a4d9;
}
```